# Error with setTypeface - android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Font resource ID could not be retrieved

Tags: android

Fonts in our apps are working correctly unless we go to screen, where the fonts are set directly in the code by function `setTypeface`:

Code is:

```
CheckBox checkButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.proactive_dialog_checkbox);
checkButton.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(activity, R.font.amatic_sc));
```

Error is:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Font resource ID #0x7f090000 could not be retrieved.
    at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.loadFont(ResourcesCompat.java:407)
    at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getFont(ResourcesCompat.java:242)
```

This code was working perfectly before we updated target API and appcompat:appcompat, now it's working in emulators in Android Studio, but not on the newest Android devices with os 11.

What we changed:

```
 compileSdkVersion from 29 -> 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29 -> 30
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 228
        versionName "228-SNAPSHOT"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
    }

dependencies{
 ...
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0' -> 1.3.1
 ...
}
```

Is it a new bug? Anybody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: did you resolve this?

Comment: nope, we just updated all code